# Cannot target Swiper slider variables as they are defined inside functions

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, swiper.js

I have 4 each functions which call a Swiper slider with the appropriate options. After those are appended to the correct div I then add the code which links them together, so one slider controls the other and vice versa.

I am getting the error "Uncaught ReferenceError: swiperV2 is not defined". I think this is because they are inside the each functions and this reference to them doesn't 'see' them.

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Thanks

```
$(".swiper-container-v").each(function(index, element) {
  var $this = $(this);
  $this.addClass("instance-" + index);
  $this.find(".swiper-button-prev").addClass("btn-prev-" + index);
  $this.find(".swiper-button-next").addClass("btn-next-" + index);
  var swiperV = new Swiper(".swiper-container-v.instance-" + index, {
      // your settings ...
      pagination: '.swiper-pagination-v',
      paginationClickable: true,
      direction: 'vertical',
      spaceBetween: 0,
      mousewheelControl: false,
      speed: 600,
      nextButton: ".btn-next-" + index,
      prevButton: ".btn-prev-" + index
  });
});

$(".swiper-container-h").each(function(index, element) {
  var $this = $(this);
  $this.addClass("instance-" + index);
  $this.find(".swiper-button-prev").addClass("btn-prev-" + index);
  $this.find(".swiper-button-next").addClass("btn-next-" + index);
  var swiperH = new Swiper(".swiper-container-h.instance-" + index, {
    // your settings ...
    pagination: '.swiper-pagination-h',
    paginationClickable: true,
    spaceBetween: 0,
    parallax: true,
    speed: 600,
    nextButton: ".btn-next-" + index,
    prevButton: ".btn-prev-" + index
  });
});



$(".swiper-container-v2").each(function(index, element) {
  var $this = $(this);
  $this.addClass("instance-" + index);
  $this.find(".swiper-button-prev").addClass("btn-prev-" + index);
  $this.find(".swiper-button-next").addClass("btn-next-" + index);
  var swiperV2 = new Swiper(".swiper-container-v2.instance-" + index, {
    // your settings ...
    paginationClickable: true,
    direction: 'vertical',
    spaceBetween: 0,
    mousewheelControl: false,
    speed: 600
  });
});


$(".swiper-container-h2").each(function(index, element) {
  var $this = $(this);
  $this.addClass("instance-" + index);
  $this.find(".swiper-button-prev").addClass("btn-prev-" + index);
  $this.find(".swiper-button-next").addClass("btn-next-" + index);
  var swiperH2 = new Swiper(".swiper-container-h2.instance-" + index, {
    // your settings ...
    paginationClickable: true,
    spaceBetween: 0,
    parallax: true,
    speed: 600
  });
});

swiperV2.params.control = swiperV;
swiperH2.params.control = swiperH;
swiperV.params.control = swiperV2;
swiperH.params.control = swiperH2;
```

Comment: I edited your code... perhaps it was just copy/pasted in funky but just want to point out that you shouldn't mix tabs/spaces and you should properly indent your code if you are not already. Sometimes it is easy to miss the obvious when our code is not cleanly organized. Be it may, you should also present your code in a cleanly formatted manner when reaching out for help as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Really.... this is just how scope works and is pretty much ubiquitous of all programming languages that are class/function based.

For you to be able to access variables that fall within the scope of a function, you must create a reference for it outside of that function in the scope that is expected to act upon it.

So in the case that you have something such as,

```
func() {
  var myVar = ...
}

print(myVar)
```

This will not work as the global scope that exists outside of the functions scope has no concept of what myVar is.

So you'll need to first create a reference to that variable.

```
var myVar;

func() {
  var myVar = ...
}

print(myVar)
```

Now since myVar was generated outside of the scope of the function, the function knows about myVar.

Alternatively you could return the value of myVar and do something like this.

```
func() {
  return myVar = ...
}

var myFunc = func();

print(myFunc())
```

And you'll have essentially performed a function assignment (i.e., assigning that function to a variable) and that variable by proxy in this case is storing the return value of the function.